# How to create like a multiple value Boolean in SwiftUI?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, swiftui, modifier

Let say I have a SwiftUI component and I want it to change color according to a parameter I choose like :

```
Component(colorValue: "1")
Component(colorValue: "2")
Component(colorValue: "3")
```

colorValue: 1 would change the color of my component to red, 2 to green, 3 to blue for example.

When I only had 2 colors in the beggining of my project I used a boolean in my component :

```
Rectangle().fill(Color(colorValue ? "red" : "blue"))
```

But now that I have multiple choice, how can I achieve the color change by checking the value of the colorValue String ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a function

```
func getColorValue() -> Color {
  if colorValue == 1 { return .red }
  // and so on
}

Rectangle().fill(Color(getColorValue()))
```